# Google Places Autocomplete returns PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED

Tags: android, google-places-autocomplete

I'm using Google Places Autocomplete API in my Application. Recently I have changed my package name. Then i have created a new project in Google Developers Console and added the API Key to my project.
I have Enabled the Google Maps SDK for Android and Places API.
Now only detecting current location is works, Places AutoComplete Search returns "PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED".

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to Enable the Google Places API for Android in **developers console** and check on the **credentials page** that your **key** is still present. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes that API is enabled and Key is still there

Answer (score 0):

Please, note that Places SDKs for Android and iOS has been updated as per this **[announcement](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/introducing-new-improved-places-sdks)**.

The Places SDK for Android (in Google Play Services 16.0.0) and Places SDK for iOS v 2.7.0 are deprecated as of January 29, 2019.

The services Places SDK for Android/iOS are not available for new users as of January 29, 2019. Please follow the instructions in the **Migration Guides** for [Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) and [iOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration) in developers' doc on how to migrate your implementation to the new versions of Places SDKs.

For using new versions of Places SDKs please ensure that Places API service is enabled on your Google Maps Platform project. Enabling Places API service makes all Places APIs available - Web Services, JavaScript and Places SDKs for Android and iOS.

Hope this helps!